# Android Studio, Kotlin, Gradle: "Run Git hooks" failes after updating to Gradle 8.0

Tags: android, git, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I've got multiple Gradle checks before a Git commit can be executed.
We updated Gradle to version 8.0. and I can't commit anymore.
If I execute a single Gradle check everything is OK and a checkmark is displayed.
However, If I want to commit I get multiple errors like these:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':util:detekt'.
Invalid value (19) passed to --jvm-target, must be one of [1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I know, it must be a problem with the version, but I don't find the right place to fix it.
It can't be in the code, because it works on a different PC.
Message: Invalid value (19) passed to --jvm-target, must be one of [1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. As expected, I had a versioning problem
Android Studio had the Kotlin plugin with version 21-1.7, according to Android Studio's latest available version.
Gradle 8.0 is based on Kotlin API level 1.8  ([Release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html)), which contradicts the Android Studio message.
I could only have updated to Kotlin 1.8-RC (unstable).

The solution was actually quite simple: **I just had to update Android Studio to the latest version!**
My version was relatively new, but there was a newer version (by 2 weeks). This update also updated Kotlin to version 1.8.

**UPDATE**:
The previous task (update) didn't finally solve my problem (Probably wrongly tested by me).
Now I have a new solution:
I'm not sure which component is responsible for the bug. It is either "Gradle" or alternatively, it could be "detect".
Whatever it was, I have a workaround:

1. Problem (Call detect via Gradle):
   The Gradle detect call (directly) works only if the Java version for Gradle in the Settings/Preferences is set to a version below Java 19 (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK.
2. Problem (Call Gradle checks while committing a change):
   The problem was my installed java version which is `openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17` according to `java -version`
   During a commit, Gradle tries to call all checks using the locally installed java version.
   There are now 2 possibilities:
   a) Everyone in the project downgrades its lokal java SDK version to below 19.
   b) Adapt `build.gradle.kts` file (In my project)
   I implemented the change in the build.gradle.kts file:
   subjects -> within `tasks.withType<io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt>().configureEach {`, I added at the beginning the line `jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()`